# how do i stop my application from crashing

Tags: android, xml

i created a simple application RealHeartRate, i linked the main activity to a new activity using a clickable text("check your heart rate") but each time i run the application the main activity(MainActivity.java) runs successfully but when i click the text("check your heart rate") which is supposed to link me to the next activity(display.java) the application crashes. I know the answer might just be staring me in the face but i simply am not that good a programmer to see it. Please what is the cause of this and how do i fix it.

Below is my code for MainActivity.java

```
    package kingsley.realheartrate;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.content.Intent;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent newActivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, display.class);


    newActivityIntent.putExtra("aString", "You have taken the wise step  of knowing your heart");


    startActivity(newActivityIntent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
 if(v.getId() == R.id.HRlink)
 {
     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, display.class);
     startActivity(i);
 }
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
    }
```

below is my code for the second activity display.java

```
   package kingsley.realheartrate;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
  import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.content.Intent;

 public class display extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Intent startingIntent = getIntent();

    String aString = startingIntent.getStringExtra("You have taken the wise step of knowing your heart");
}
}
```

Below is my Android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="kingsley.realheartrate">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".display"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

This is the code for activity_main.xml

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context="kingsley.realheartrate.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I will really appreciate if someone can take a look at this and help with a solution.

Comment: what error happened? Attach stack trace pls

Comment: it might not be the cause for your crash, but if you want to get the string from your intent, you have to use the same key. In your display activity, you want to get the string with `getStringExtra("You have taken the wise step of knowing your heart");` . But it must be `getStringExtra("aString");`

Comment: Your code seems fine, but maybe the error is because somewhere you are not using AppCompat whereas in some places you are using it. I am not sure, please post logcat to check what actually the error is.

Comment: here is the logcat

Comment: here is the logcat   kingsley.realheartrate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   Process: kingsley.realheartrate, PID: 2822
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Check Your HeartRate(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class                 @Damini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
String aString = startingIntent.getStringExtra("You have taken the wise step of knowing your heart");
```

with it...this will protect app to crash

```
String aString="";
try{
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

  if (extras != null) {
   aString = extras.getString("aString");
  }
}catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String aString = startingIntent.getStringExtra("You have taken the wise step of knowing your heart");

  //change this to 

  String aString = startingIntent.getStringExtra("aString");
```

You are supposed to give key here..

Comment: yes if the string is not found it returns null. Anyway, not the cause of the crash....

Comment: I know what you mean, but in that way, you are risking to get downvotes because it´s not the answer. Wait until the questioner give us some light about the problem with stacktrace, and if you then know the answer, post this above as a part of it....

Answer (score 0):

as you haven't posted your layout file of the second activity i will guess that you don't have any toobar on that layout and the activity crashes on that

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

inside the  `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: acitivity_display.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone, what i did to solve the problem was to make the onClick method same as what is declared in my main_activity.xml file and it worked. The idea is to look at the logcat file to find why the application is crashing. thanks again